# Approach to override (s)printf function, with code in .c file in GCC project?

Tags: c, gcc, printf

I have seen this in https://github.com/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS-Kernel/blob/main/include/task.h :

> ```
> An alternative, tiny, third party, and limited  
> * functionality implementation of sprintf() is provided in many of the  
> * FreeRTOS/Demo sub-directories in a file called printf-stdarg.c (note 
> * printf-stdarg.c does not provide a full snprintf() implementation!).
> ```

Ok, so I would like to attempt to replace `sprintf()` in this way, via `printf-stdarg.c`, in my project too - except there isn't such an example for my MCU.

So, I tried to look at other examples, which first and foremost need to be Makefile/gcc, because that is what I use for my MCU. Eventually, I found this project:

- https://github.com/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS/tree/main/FreeRTOS/Demo/lwIP_AVR32_UC3

... which apparently uses [`printf-stdarg.c`](https://github.com/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS/blob/main/FreeRTOS/Demo/lwIP_AVR32_UC3/printf-stdarg.c).

So, I look at what looks like a corresponding Makefile - that is, [config.mk](https://github.com/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS/blob/main/FreeRTOS/Demo/lwIP_AVR32_UC3/AT32UC3A/GCC/config.mk) - and only thing relevant I can see, is this:

```
...
CSRCS = \
  $(BRDS_PATH)/EVK1100/led.c \
..
  $(DEMO_PATH)/main.c \
...
  $(DEMO_PATH)/printf-stdarg.c

# Assembler source files
...
DEBUG = -g
...
OPTIMIZATION = -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
...
CPP_EXTRA_FLAGS =
...
C_EXTRA_FLAGS =
...
AS_EXTRA_FLAGS =
...
LD_EXTRA_FLAGS = -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-e,_trampoline
...
```

So, I don't really see anything special related to the overload, apart from `printf-stdarg.c` being added as last in the list of source .c files of the project.

So, I tried doing that in my project - just added a `printf-stdarg.c` to this list of compiled files - and while the build completes succesfully, I doubt anything has been replaced/overloaded, since if I inspect with:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-readelf -s my_program.elf | grep 'stdarg'
$
```

... I get no file names that contain 'stdarg' in the list of source file paths, that ended up in the compiled program.

So, in principle - how is this "overload"/"replacement" of (s)printf, with code in a self-contained .c file, supposed to work?

Is it "just" add the source file "last" in the list of source files to be sure it is compiled (well, probably not, judging from my results above) - or does one also have to do additional steps (maybe change linking order of object files; or add some additional code in my `main.c`; or add special linker flags)? If there is a need for additional steps - what are those?

Comment: You're fine. It _will_ link in `printf-stdarg.o`. But, the file defines (e.g.) the `sprintf` symbol but _no_ symbol with `stdarg` so the `grep` _will_ fail. Just because the filename has `stdarg` in it does not mean the symbols have it. If you look at the full `readelf -s` output you'll see that `sprintf` is defined _in_ the executable itself--which _is_ what you want (i.e.) it is _not_ just an external reference.

Comment: This can be verified by looking at the make output. You will see the compile of the `printf-stdarg.c` file and the linking of `printf-stdarg.o`